# React-Native displaying image from blob

Tags: image, react-native, blob

I'm pulling from an API that gives me back an image in a blob inside the response. I need to display this image somewhere. I tried using react-native-fetch-blob, but its clear that that's a complete mess. I'm guessing there has to be some way I can convert it to base64 so that the image can be displayed.